# My app is crashing after writing layout manager object

Tags: java, android

After writing: `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`, this code in my application crashes. Please help me solve this problem. I don't know what I'm missing. I am trying to make Recycler view for my app. Package:  `com.example.recylclervieww;`

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.recylclervieww.adapter.RecipeAdapter;
import com.example.recylclervieww.models.recipemodel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);`enter code here`
        ArrayList<recipemodel>list=new ArrayList();
        list.add(new recipemodel(R.id.imageView,"food lover"));
         list.add(new recipemodel(R.id.imageView,"food lover"));
         list.add(new recipemodel(R.id.imageView,"food lover"));
         list.add(new recipemodel(R.id.imageView,"food lover"));
         list.add(new recipemodel(R.id.imageView,"food lover"));
         list.add(new recipemodel(R.id.imageView,"food lover"));
         list.add(new recipemodel(R.id.imageView,"food lover"));
         list.add(new recipemodel(R.id.imageView,"food lover"));
         list.add(new recipemodel(R.id.imageView,"food lover"));
         list.add(new recipemodel(R.id.imageView,"food lover"));

        RecipeAdapter adapter =new RecipeAdapter(list,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =new LinearLayoutManager(this );`enter code here`
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);enter code here



    }
}`




package com.example.recylclervieww.models;

public class recipemodel {
    public recipemodel(int pic, String text) {
        this.pic = pic;
        this.text = text;
    }

    int pic;


    public int getPic() {
        return pic;
    }

    public void setPic(int pic) {
        this.pic = pic;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    String text;


}


package com.example.recylclervieww.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.recylclervieww.R;
import com.example.recylclervieww.models.recipemodel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecipeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeAdapter.viewHolder> {
    ArrayList<recipemodel>list;
    Context context;

    public RecipeAdapter(ArrayList<recipemodel> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_recycler ,parent,false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
        recipemodel model=list.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(model.getPic());
        holder.textView.setText(model.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class `viewHolder` extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        }
    }
}**
```

Comment: You misspell "recycler" as "recylcler", and "view" as "vieww" multiple times in your code. Please make sure you spell everything correctly, and then update your question.

Answer (score 0):

**What's Happening?**

Setting layout manager after attaching the adapter is not the correct implementation.

**Solution**

**Replace this**

```
RecipeAdapter adapter =new RecipeAdapter(list,this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =new LinearLayoutManager(this );`enter code here`
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);enter code here
```

**With this**

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =new LinearLayoutManager(this );
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
RecipeAdapter adapter =new RecipeAdapter(list,this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```